# Adding filters/effects to images in ios 9

Tags: ios, filter, uiimage, uiimagepickercontroller, ios9

*Are there any* ***easy*** **or** ***open source tools*** **or** ***Apple commands*** *to add filters to an ios 9 app I am building?*

*The app uses the image picker.*

Comment: [Are you talking about this?](https://www.cocoacontrols.com/search?q=camera)

Answer (score 0):

Use [CIFilter](https://developer.apple.com/library/prerelease/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/QuartzCoreFramework/Classes/CIFilter_Class/) implemented in Core Image.

Comment: I see that they added a lot. Are there any good examples of applying a CIFilter as I am new to Core Image tasks?

Answer (score 0):

I have once used [GPUImage](https://github.com/BradLarson/GPUImage). You can use it to add filters and other effects to images, live camera video, and movies.You can read the documentation its very easy to implement.